# background image and reset button for user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that allows users to upload and change the background image, I need help to add the **reset button** and, if possible, css advice for the upload and reset buttons, Thanks.

```js
$(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
    switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
  if (backgroundImage) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');
  } 
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

Comment: what do you want the reset button to do?

Comment: to remove the background image, thanks

Comment: make a function which sets the 'body' css property to  background-image:none

Comment: if you would like to show me an example code, you will help me a lot, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like this. This will set the background-image to nothing.

```
function resetBackgroundImage() {
 if ($('body').css('background-image') != 'none') 
    $('body').css({'background-image': 'none'}); 
}
```